# How do you solve this step by step? Exponential and logarithmic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Please help on my homework on exponential and logarithmic functions:

[Exponential & Logarithmic Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJmB7.jpg)
EDIT: Question is on the link

Comment: You could start by using the rule that $\log(A/B) = \log(A) - \log(B)$ (assuming $A$ and $B$ are positive numbers).

Comment: Drop a little work and we will give you some advice.

Answer (score 3):

Familiarize yourself with the basic properties of logarithms.

$$
ln\left(\frac{A}{B}\right) = ln(A) - ln(B)
$$
$$
ln(A^x) = x\cdot ln(A)
$$ 
The above should help.

Make sure you understand what a logarithm to the base $e$ is if you do not already and the answer should follow immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Ans:B

$x-ln(1+e^x)$

write the $x$ in the expression as $ln (e)^x$ so that the expression becomes $ln (e)^x$$-ln(1+e^x)$ that is $ln\frac{ (e)^x}{1+e^x}$ because

$ln(\frac{C}{D}) = ln(C) - ln(D)$